# Why are there two different recurrences for Gegenbauer polynomials?

Tags: special-functions, harmonic-analysis

As I mentioned [previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129412/what-do-gegenbauer-polynomials-have-to-do-with-the-birthday-problem), I've been reading up on Gegenbauer polynomials in preparation for a blog post on the kissing number problem—specifically, the Delsarte method.

To make a long story short, the method involves expressing a particular function as a non-negative linear sum of Gegenbauer polynomials.  In various publications on this topic (see, for example, Musin, "[The Kissing Number in Four Dimensions](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v168-n1-p01.pdf)" in the July 2008 *Annals of Mathematics*), these polynomials have the following recurrence:

$$
G^{(n)}_0(t) = 1
$$
$$
G^{(n)}_1(t) = t
$$
$$
G^{(n)}_k(t) = \frac{(2k+n-4)tG^{(n)}_{k-1}(t)-(k-1)G^{(n)}_{k-2}(t)}{k+n-3}
$$

However, in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials) and [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GegenbauerPolynomial.html) plot summaries for Gegenbauer polynomials, the recurrences are different (and not just up to a constant factor).  In both, converting to consistent symbols, we have

$$
G^{(n)}_0(t) = 1
$$
$$
G^{(n)}_1(t) = 2nt
$$
$$
G^{(n)}_k(t) = \frac{2t(k+n-1)G^{(n)}_{k-1}(t)-(k+2n-2)G^{(n)}_{k-2}(t)}{k}
$$

Both definitions are normalized to $G^{(n)}_0(t) = 1$.  What accounts for the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $G$ for the second definition and $\widetilde G$ for the first definition. $G$ has the generating function $(1 - 2 x t + t^2)^{-n}$:
$$(1 - 2 x t + t^2)^{-n} = \sum_{k \geq 0} G_k^{(n)}(x) \,t^k.$$
$\widetilde G$ is constructed by first taking $C$ with the gf $(1 - 2 x t + t^2)^{1 -n/2}$ and then normalizing by $C(1)$:
$$(1 - 2 x t + t^2)^{1 - n/2} = \sum_{k \geq 0} C_k^{(n)}(x) \,t^k, \\
\widetilde G_k^{(n)}(x) = \frac {C_k^{(n)}(x)} {C_k^{(n)}(1)}.$$
Therefore
$$\widetilde G_k^{(n)}(x) =
\frac {(-1)^k} {\binom {2 - n} k } G_k^{(n/2 - 1)}(x).$$

Comment: Interesting.  Can you say something about why this difference exists?  Is there a particular reason why one formulation should be preferred for some applications, and the other formulation for other applications?

Comment: I suppose it's a question of which makes the formulas less cumbersome for a particular application. Wikipedia gives a number of relations for $G_k^{(n)}$ and mentions that $G_k^{(n/2 - 1)}$ are spherical harmonics. The cited paper uses the fact that the matrix $(\widetilde G_k^{(n)}(\mathbf x_i \cdot \mathbf x_j))$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: OK.  At any rate, that's worth the bounty.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some aspects which might help to clarify the situation.  At first I'd like to give a few *definitions* of Gegenbauer polynomials from relevant sources. This way  we can get an impression what we typically might expect.

> *[Higher Transcendental Functions,  Vol I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CIK7O)* by A. Erdelyi and H. Bateman (author):
>
> - (3.15.1. Gegenbauer polynomials)
>
>   Gegenbauer's polynomial $C_n^{\nu}(z)$ for integral value $n$ is defined to be the coefficient of $h^n$ in the expansion of $(1-2hz+h^2)^{-\nu}$ in powers of $h$;
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1-2hz+h^2)^{-\nu}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n^{\nu}(z)h^n\qquad\qquad|h|<|z\pm(z^2-1)^{1/2}|
> \end{align*}
>
> *[Handbook of Mathematical Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486612724)* by M. Abramowitz, I.A. Stegun:
>
> - (22.9.3. Generating Functions)
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1-2xz+z^2)^{-\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n^{(\alpha)}(x)z^n\qquad\qquad |z|<1,\alpha\ne 0
> \end{align*}
>
> *[NIST/DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/18.12)*
>
> - (18.12.4. Ultraspherical)
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1-2xz+z^2)^{-\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n^{(\alpha)}(x)z^n\qquad\qquad |z|<1
> \end{align*}
>
> *[Special Functions, Encyclopedia of mathematics and its applications 71](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521789885)* by G.E. Andrews, R. Askey and R. Roy:
>
> - (6.4 Generating Functions for Jacobi Polynomials)
>
>   It is reasonable to define polynomials
>
> \begin{align*}
> C_n^{\lambda}(x):=\frac{(2\lambda)_n}{(\lambda+(1/2))_n}P_n^{(\lambda-(1/2),\lambda-(1/2))}(x)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> $\qquad$with the generating function
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1-2xr+r^2)^{-\lambda}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n^{\lambda}(x)r^n.\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Note the exponent of $(1-2xr+r^2)^{\color{blue}{-\lambda}}$ and the upper index in $C_n^{\color{blue}{\lambda}}(x)$ in (2) are coupled by a multiplicative factor $-1$ and this notational convention is used in *all* these citations. The connection with the *[Jacobi polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials)* is given     in (1).

> We take a look at OPs cited paper *[The Kissing Number in Four Dimensions](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v168-n1-p01.pdf)* by O.R. Musin, check a few statements and a cited reference we are interested in.
>
> - *(3.B The Gegenbauer polynomials)*
>
>   ... Let us recall definitions of Gegenbauer polynomials $C_k^{(n)}(t)$, which are defined by the expansion
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1-2rt+r^2)^{(2-n)/2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^kC_k^{(n)}(t)\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

This   definition  looks   somewhat  peculiar, since  the  upper  index  $n$  of $C_k^{(\color{blue}{n})}$  is not coupled by a factor $-1$  with the exponent of $(1-2rt+r^2)^{\color{blue}{(2-n)/2}}$  of the generating function. A few lines above (3.B)  the author states

> ... Schoenberg [29] extended this property to Gegenbauer polynomials $G_k^{(n)}$. He proved: The matrix $\left(G_k^{(n)}\left(\cos \phi_{i,j}\right)\right)$ is positive semidefinite for any finite $X\subseteq \mathbf{S}^{n-1}$.

The reference [29] addresses the paper *[Positive definite functions on spheres](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077493072)* by I.J. Schoenberg. It is revealing to check the definition Schoenberg used for Gegenbauer (resp. ultraspherical) polynomials.

> - (Schoenberg [29], section 1)
>
>   ... Let $P_n^{(\lambda)}(\cos t)$ be the ultraspherical polynomials defined by the expansion
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1-2r\cos t+r^2)^{-\lambda}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^nP_n^{(\lambda)}(\cos t),\qquad\qquad (\lambda>0).\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

Note in definition (4) the parameter $\lambda$ is used in accordance with the citations above. A few lines later Schoenberg gives a series expansion of a function $g(t)$ in terms of Gegenbauer polynomials:

> - (Schoenberg [29], section 1)
>
>   ... The most general element of $\mathcal{P}(S_m)$ is
>
> \begin{align*}
> g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n^{(\lambda)}(\cos t),\qquad\qquad(\lambda=\frac{1}{2}(m-1)),\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

**Conclusion:** Comparing Schoenberg's usage of the parameter $\lambda$ in (5) and (4)  with  Musin's parameter setting in (3) indicates he could have had some short-cut notation in mind.  Regrettably this implies that recurrence relation, differential equations, etc. have a different  form than usually expected. The differences in the recurrence  relation do not occur, if Musin would have  used (3') instead

\begin{align*}
(1-2rt+r^2)^{-\lambda}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^kC_k^{(\lambda)}(t)\qquad\qquad (\lambda=(n-2)/2)\tag{3'}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!

Comment: @BrianTung: You're welcome.